# How to get discount items in cart

Tags: discount

How do I get the Shopping cart discounts? 
For a payment integration I need to sent all items in cart.
For products that is easy, but how do I get the following for all applied discounts:

- amount with and without tax
- name
- vat%

Answer (score 4):

Hi you can get this **details using cart  session**

```
$totals = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getTotals(); //Total object
$subtotal = $totals["subtotal"]->getValue(); //Subtotal value
$grandtotal = $totals["grand_total"]->getValue(); //Grandtotal value
if(isset($totals['discount']) && $totals['discount']->getValue()) {
 $discount = Mage::helper('core')->currency($totals['discount']->getValue()); //Discount value if applied
} else {
 $discount = '';
}




if(isset($totals['tax']) && $totals['tax']->getValue()) {
 $tax = $totals['tax']->getValue(); //Tax value if present
} else {
 $tax = '';
}
```

### You can get details by Checkout session

```
$quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();
```

### TO get the list of items in the cart :

```
$cartItems = $quote->getAllVisibleItems();
```

### For getting each item and it details and discount :

```
foreach ($cartItems as $item) {
    echo $item->getQty();
$item->getPrice();
$item->getDiscountAmount();
}
```

For getting coupon code try this **Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()getCouponCode();**
more details to check table `sales_flat_quote_item` in your magento system

Comment: $tax = $totals['tax']->getValue(); --> This is the total tax, not tax on the discount.

You did not answer how to get the name of the discount.